# Incorrect data displayed in lightning datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-message-service, lightning-message-channel

I have a LWC which takes value from 3 input fields and passes the value to a separate component with lightning datatable via LMS. I am able to pass the data for the first time but when I try to repeat the process all the values in the array are updated to the latest value.

Publisher Component HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Input Data">
        <lightning-input class="slds-m-around_medium" type="text" data-id="name" label="Enter Name" onchange={inputHandler}></lightning-input>
        <lightning-input class="slds-m-around_medium" type="text" data-id="phone" label="Enter Phone" onchange={inputHandler}></lightning-input>
        <lightning-input class="slds-m-around_medium" type="text" data-id="country" label="Enter Country" onchange={inputHandler}></lightning-input>
        <lightning-button class="slds-m-around_medium" label="Send Data" variant="brand" onclick={dataHandler}></lightning-button>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Publisher Component JS:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { publish, MessageContext } from 'lightning/messageService';
import SEND_MESSAGE from '@salesforce/messageChannel/Send_Message__c';

export default class DataFiller extends LightningElement {


name;
phone;
country;

@wire(MessageContext)
messageContext;

records=[];
data={};

inputHandler(event){
    if(event.target.dataset.id == 'name'){
        this.name = event.target.value;
        this.data.Name = this.name;
        console.log(this.data);
    }
    else if(event.target.dataset.id == 'phone'){
        this.phone = event.target.value;
        this.data.Phone = this.phone;
        console.log(this.data);
    }
    else{
        this.country = event.target.value;
        this.data.Country = this.country;
        console.log(this.data);
    }
}

dataHandler(){
    this.records.push(this.data);
    let payload = this.records;
    publish(this.messageContext, SEND_MESSAGE, payload);
}
```

Subscriber Component HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Person Details">
        <lightning-datatable columns={columns} key-field="Id" data={data}>           
        </lightning-datatable>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Subscriber Component JS:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { subscribe, MessageContext } from 'lightning/messageService';
import SEND_MESSAGE from '@salesforce/messageChannel/Send_Message__c';

export default class PersonTable extends LightningElement {

    columns = [{ label : 'Name', fieldName: 'Name'},
                 { label : 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone'},
                 { label : 'Country', fieldName: 'Country'}];

    data;
    subscription=null;

    @wire(MessageContext)
    messageContext;

    subscriptionToMessageChannel(){
        this.subscription=subscribe(this.messageContext, SEND_MESSAGE, (messageToSend) => this.handleMessage(messageToSend));
    }

    connectedCallback(){
        this.subscriptionToMessageChannel();
        console.log('Subscribed');
    }

    handleMessage(messageToSend){
        this.data = messageToSend;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.data))
    }

}
```

[image: When the data is send for the First time]

[image: When the data is sent for the second time]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not resetting `data` variable due to that same value adding again.

We can get all value on button click.

In below code snippet we are query input with latest LWC update `lwc:ref`.

**HTML file**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Input Data">
        <lightning-input class="slds-m-around_medium" type="text" label="Enter Name" lwc:ref="name"></lightning-input>
        <lightning-input class="slds-m-around_medium" type="text" label="Enter Phone" lwc:ref="phone"></lightning-input>
        <lightning-input class="slds-m-around_medium" type="text" label="Enter Country" lwc:ref="country"></lightning-input>
        <lightning-button class="slds-m-around_medium" label="Send Data" variant="brand" onclick={dataHandler}></lightning-button>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**JS file**

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { publish, MessageContext } from 'lightning/messageService';
import SEND_MESSAGE from '@salesforce/messageChannel/Send_Message__c';
export default class Component1 extends LightningElement {
    name;
    phone;
    country;

    @wire(MessageContext)
    messageContext;

    records=[];

    dataHandler(){
        let name = this.refs?.name?.value;
        let phone = this.refs?.phone?.value;
        let country = this.refs?.country?.value;
        this.records.push({Name : name, Phone : phone, Country : country});
        publish(this.messageContext, SEND_MESSAGE, this.records);
    }
}
```

**Output:**
[image: Output]

Ref : https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_templaterefs.htm&release=242&type=5

Answer (score 1):

`data` is never reset, so you're pushing the same object onto the Array. You need to make a new object every time you want a new row.

```
dataHandler(){
    this.records.push(this.data);
    let { name: Name, phone: Phone, country: Country } = this;
    this.data = { Name, Phone, Country };
    let payload = this.records;
    publish(this.messageContext, SEND_MESSAGE, payload);
}
```

If you want to preserve the input for some reason, do so by copying, instead:

```
    this.data = {...this.data};
```

Comment: First solution will not help here because if we reset variable then when we click on button again then it will not get value from input.

Comment: @A.K. That's a separate issue, though I suppose I should mention here. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Thank you both. The answer is really helpful and I am able to resolve it.